# How can I change DateTime to am and pm instead of AM/PM for C#

Tags: c#, android, appium

Here is the code I am using below

```
    string Time = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy h:mm tt");
```

The above tt will give me AM or PM but I need am or pm. Is there a different way to write this to get am or pm in C#? I have tried TT,t leaving it out completely but all end in failure.

Comment: Since everything else in the generated string are just numbers, why not applying string replacements for AM->am and PM->pm on the string produced by DateTime.Now.ToString(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yy h:mm tt").ToLower();
```